# Correct way to update Core Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to update my Core Data stack when a button gets pressed. it all looks fine when the app is running in one session, but when I restart the app the update I made no longer exist.

My code looks like this:

```
if let indexPath = self.tv.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point){
    let data = messageList[indexPath.row] as Messages
    if data.read == true{
        println("Message already read")
    }else{
        data.read = true
    }
 }
```

Why does this happen? The change always get reverted when my app is being restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure, that you call `save` on the `NSManagedObjectContext` instance. There should be at least on call already defined in `AppDelegate`, but you might want to call it more often, e.g. when your app enters the background or on similar occasions.

For further reference, take a look at [iOS Core Data when to save context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457847/ios-core-data-when-to-save-context)

Answer (score 1):

You nedd to save NSManagedObjectContext before close your application.

For example: 
AppDelegate.swift

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    self.saveContext()
}
```

This works only if you kill the app.

But if you want to save context after any change in NSManagedObject, you need to call mangedObjectContext.save(&error)

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot! :)